# Specifying python version when using `generic` image in travis-ci for a project with both C and Python

Tags: python, c, unit-testing, python-3.6, travis-ci

I have a project using both C (and the GSL library) and Python.  I am hoping to run tests in Python after installing the GSL library.  Travis-CI allows `generic` images which include both the `gcc` compiler and Python so this sounds ideal for this project.  I cannot seem to specify the Python version to use for `pip` and `python` calls.  The following `.travis.yml` build fails and the log shows that pytest is using Python 2.7.  I've tried `python3 -m pytest` and also tried using `pip3` but neither has worked.  How can I specify the version of python (3.6.2) so that both pip install modules for this version of python and pytest is run for this version of python under the `generic` image?

Many thanks in advance for the help.

```
language: generic
dist: xenial
env: PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.2
python: 3.6
before_install: 
  - sudo apt-get install libgsl-dev
install:
  - pip install --user -r tests/requirements.txt
script:
  - pytest
```

Comment: is my answer working ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  No, it failed, `The command "sudo apt-get install libgsl-dev python3-pytest" failed and exited with 100 during`.

Comment: There's no `python3-pytest` within `pip` or `pip3` so I assume you meant via `apt-get`.

Comment: yes apt-get this is what I did under raspbian. It seems you are under xenial, it is strange because *python3-pytest* is the right name also for xenial : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/python3-pytest

Comment: what appends if you install python3-pytest by hand before rather than through the yaml file ?

Comment: What do you mean 'by hand'?

Comment: to do "sudo apt-get install python3-pytest" yourself in a terminal

Answer (score 0):

If you have *python3* and *pip3* that means *pytest* is for *python 2* like *python* and *pip*

Install *python3-pytest* then specify *pytest-3* rather than *pytest* for the *script*, probably also use *pip3* rather than *pip* for *install*